# How to use easy install on Canopy Enthought?

Tags: python, pip, enthought, easy-install, canopy

I have installed the latest version of Enthought, I have the free express version. and I want to install the pyodbc package.

I have gathered that I need to use easy_install to install pip to install pyodbc.

However, I have no luck in using easy_install or even enpkg.

If I open enthought editor and type in:

```
enpkg pip
```

or

```
easy_install pip
```

all I am getting in return is syntax errors.

(I am very inexperienced with using external packaged that are not already installed into Enthought.)

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are the syntax errors? I am guessing you are typing this into the python shell shown by the enthought editor?

What you need to do is open up a command shell. Are you on Windows? Try running `cmd.exe` - Canopy might even provide a special shell to use (with paths all set up for you) so check the start menu.

Then, you should be able to use `easy_install` and `enpkg`. You should see a prompt similar to:

```
C:\Users\Sameer\>
```

Type it at that prompt.

The python prompt looks like this:

```
>>>
```

You can't run `enpkg` or `easy_install` from there. Well... technically you can by shelling out, but first, try the above.

Comment: I feel stupid but this seems to have worked! Thanks, I may delete this question but thanks for your help!

Comment: For the record: as Daren guessed, there is indeed a Canopy Command Prompt (Windows) or Canopy Terminal (Mac or Linux) which opens with paths already set up.